# phpSlim post function inserting null data

Tags: php, slim

i am using php slim framework 3
my function is inserting null instead of data

```
function addstud(Request $request, Response $response)
{

$stud = $request->getParsedBody();
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (`name`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (':name', ':username', ':password')";
try {
    $db = GetDatabase();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("name", $stud->name);
    $stmt->bindParam("username", $stud->username);
    $stmt->bindParam("password", $stud->password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stud->id = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($stud);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
   }
}
```

can any one help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried to `dd($stud);` to make sure the 'name', 'username' and 'password' attributes are there? If they do exist do you need to do `$stmt->bindParam(":name", $stud->name);` etc instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding parameters incorrectly: you forgot colon. So, instead of

```
$stmt->bindParam("name", $stud->name);
$stmt->bindParam("username", $stud->username);
$stmt->bindParam("password", $stud->password);
```

You should do

```
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $stud->name);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $stud->username);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $stud->password);
```